# Resizing Square Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently creating a "number pad" for inputting phone numbers into a text field. I want my buttons to be square, and I want them to dynamically re size to fit the window. The problem is that if I set them to be a percentage of the view height, and then make the width small, they don't re-size to fit the width, and if I set them to be a percentage of the view width, and shrink the height, they don't re-size to fit the height. How can I achieve this effect (ex. I want the button to be 20vh by 20vh OR 20vw by 20vw, whichever is smaller). I would like to avoid using javascript if that is at all possible. Here is my current code:

HTML:

```
<table>
            <tr class="numberPadRow">
                <td></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary numberPadButton" value="0" onclick="appendValue(this);"> 0 </button></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary numberPadButton" value="0" onclick="appendValue(this);"> 0 </button></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary numberPadButton" value="0" onclick="appendValue(this);"> 0 </button></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```
.numberPadButton {
    width: 20vh;
    height: 20vh;
}
```

Additionally I have been trying to center the three buttons on the screen, if anyone can help with that that would be amazing :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tables for layout....arggg!

Comment: Perhaps `vmin` or `vmax` ??

Comment: I know, I wanted to avoid tables as well however I couldn't think of a better way to group buttons by threes, I think it has just been too long a day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution without javascript would be to utilize `max-width` and `max-height`.

```
.square {
    width: 20vh;
    height: 20vh;
    max-height: 20vw;
    max-width: 20vw;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmsn057h/

Comment: brilliant, I was thinking of using max-height/width but for some reason the idea of using vh for the regular one and vw for the max didn't occur to me!